# Can doors be closed in Imperial Assault?

Tags: star-wars-imperial-assault

Say that a figure opens a door. Can it later be closed by either the Rebels or the Imperials (perhaps with the intention of blocking line of sight or hindering movement)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Players cannot close doors after they are opened, only game effects can close an open doorway.

From the [Rules Reference Guide](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/filer_public/ef/86/ef866943-534b-429e-b8db-7d99875431b7/imperial_assault_rules_reference_guide.pdf) (page 11 under **Doors**)

> If an effect closes a door, place a door token on the map as
>   shown on the mission’s map. **Figures cannot voluntarily close
>   doors.**